# PHP| Mysql - Image next and previous button

Tags: php, mysql, image, gallery

I made a image gallery, right now I have problem with displaying pictures and 'next/previous' button.

As you can see below, the bigger picture is the main picture 'view_gallery.php?id=??'
While the rest are the different picture.

Is there any way to make this more neat?
 How do I make a box/ table to store the images from my database, to be more neat, with the previous and next button.

[image]

This is a screenshot from imgur, the rest of the pictures are stored in a next box thingy
[image]

My lecturer told me about 'image-buffer'(I'm sure I misheard what she said)

PS. I googled image-buffer and I got Adobe After Effects stuffs. I think that's not it.

Comment: I guess he meant you should pre-load the next picture while being invisible for the user. That way, when a user clicks next, the image will appear instantaneously.

Comment: if i understand your problem correctly. The solution is a matter of CSS + Javascript. `css` to put the image on a box and hide some images and javascript to create a slide of image.

Comment: I think that what she meant. What are the languages required to make a 'prev/next' for image gallery?

Comment: Thank you @ROMMEL . That is exactly my problem xD Right now I am reading about this Colorbox Jquery thingy. Thanks \o